# How to make text on a webpage appear to be readable English but is actually illegible?

Tags: css, fonts, html

I'm looking to obfuscate some text by making it completely illegible.

While this is very easy to do in handwriting, I need it to be done on a webpage in Verdana.

I was thinking that I could possibly make a Verdana-esque font that has the top and bottom halves of many letters switched, or I could overlap lines of text such that it becomes an unreadable mess.

An alternative would be to use DeepStyle images in place of text.

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Just curious, why would you want to do this?

Comment: To represent text that the reader is incapable of comprehending

Comment: There are so many options. Your question itself names some of them: use a handwriting font, set the line-height to something smaller than 1ex, etc. How about using an online webservice to translate your text to a foreign language, or to add diacritics - you know, Zalgo text. Or, foregreound color #040 and background color #404. The possibilities are endless!

Comment: But now I'm unsure whether to close as too broad or as primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This q might be closed, but wth, here's something, with an idea from [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/blurry-text/) (blur), plus my own thrown in.

```css
p {
    font-family: verdana;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

.blur {
   color: transparent;
   text-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<p class="blur">
    Now that we know who you are, I know who I am. I'm not a mistake! 
It all makes sense! In a comic, you know how you can tell who the 
arch-villain's going to be? He's the exact opposite of the hero. 
And most times they're friends, like you and me! I should've known 
way back when... You know why, David? Because of the kids. They 
called me Mr Glass.
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Or perhaps a `text-shadow` solution?

```css
#mangle {
text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em,
      -0.1em 0.1em,
      0.1em -0.1em,
      -0.1em -0.1em;
}
```

```html
<p id="mangle">Sufficiently obfuscated?</p>
```